# Permissions tar extraction to nfs share from a Perl script

Tags: linux, tar, perl, nfs, curl

As part of an installation procedure of a piece of software, I use:

```
curl -s <url-to-targz> | tar -p -x -z -C /
```

inside a Perl script  (I use `qx($command)` or `system($command)`, either will do.All goes well, and the tar ball is installed to the / of my system, but when I do the same thing to an nfs share:

```
curl -s <url-to-targz> | tar -p -x -z -C /my-nfs/opt
```

Then the following occurs:

- When I do this on the prompt, this goes well (i.e. all my permissions that I saved in the tar ball are still in place).
- When I do this from withing the Perl script (or a shell script, for that matter), either `qx($command)` or `system($command)` leaves me in with the situation that the permissions are changed (for example, what was executable, is no longer executable).

I am suspecting this has to do with umask (which is 022 on my system), and normally the -p flag should take care of that, but still no joy in this case. Does anyone have any suggestions for me (other than read the manpage :-))?

I have also tried something like `system("umask xyz; $command")`, but (probably because the `$command` is using a fork of my process, which gets the `umask 022`): also no joy.

Edit: Some of the answers indicate I should use umask of Perl. I think a umask 000 will do the trick (but I will see this in the morning, when I am at the system. umask though, has a different effect on files and directories. Is there a way to disable umask entirely during the run of my progran (despite a thousand security reasons against it).

Comment: When you run this command on the prompt, are you `root`? I think  `tar -p` also saves the owner (I'm really not sure, the man is vague), which won't work as normal user. Perhaps that's a problem?!

Comment: Indeed, I run it as root. When running as normal user, -p does not restore permissions in the right fashion. As root, it should. Also, there is user:group information safed in the tar ball, which you can't restore when running tar as non-root

Comment: And it's working as root also on the NFS mount? I suspected that the error is due to the fact that lots of nfsd are configures to map `root` to `nobody` (option `rootsquash`).

Comment: I belive there's a perl function to change the program umask. Or, perhaps `"umask xyz && $command"` would work.